# How to deal with slashes in xml node values?

Tags: xml, libxml2

I'm using libxml2 to parse XML files. My problem is that when slashes"/" are present in a node value like :

```
<Chunk>
    <Path>ef09cf15-f3d2-4f23-a281-32757d6b0be6/Bigfoot_Trl_A_France_FLAT.xml</Path>
    <VolumeIndex>1</VolumeIndex>
    <Length>5056</Length>
</Chunk>
```

adn if I perform :

```
if (!xmlStrcmp(item_leaf->name, (const xmlChar *)"Path"))
{
   path =  (char *) item_leaf->xmlChildrenNode->content;
}
```

That only gives me the substing before the "/" so : ef09cf15-f3d2-4f23-a281-32757d6b0be6

How can I solve the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does [`item_leaf->xmlNodeGetContent()`](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-tree.html#xmlNodeGetContent) give you the full value?

Comment: Hi, thanks, I just tried it but that changes nothing...

Comment: xmlNodeGetContent() should provide the full value.  Can you provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the behavior?